# Hibernate exception handling of session.save - thread getting hung

Tags: hibernate, exception

I was trying to work on the Hibernate Exception handling.
I am trying to persist to a table and getting a runtime exception (expected as created deliberately) but am unable to catch the exception from session.save method.

Here is the code

```
@Override
public void persist(News entity) {
    try {
        currentSession.save(entity);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        if(currentTransaction != null) {
            currentTransaction.rollback();
        }
        if(currentSession != null) {
            currentSession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the exception

```
 Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence with (updlock, rowlock)
    Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
    Hibernate: insert into News (url, newsid) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into NewsDetail (articleBody, datemodified, datepublished, description, headline, newsid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Apr 20, 2018 10:37:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 241, SQLState: S0001
    Apr 20, 2018 10:37:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
    Apr 20, 2018 10:37:17 AM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
    ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1442)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
        at com. .hibernate.dao.NewsDao.closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction(NewsDao.java:41)
        at com.wion.hibernate.service.NewsService.persist(NewsService.java:19)
        at com.wion.base.launch.Wion.persist(Wion.java:74)
        at com.wion.base.launch.Wion.main(Wion.java:42)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3018)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3533)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
        ... 20 more
```

As a result, thread is getting hung because the rollback call is not going to DB.

What could be the reason ?

Adding config

```
<session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test;integratedSecurity=true</property>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Adding entity

```
package com.wion.database.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTables;
import javax.persistence.Table;

//import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name="News")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="NewsClassification",pkJoinColumns= {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="newsid")}),
    @SecondaryTable(name="NewsDetail",pkJoinColumns= {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="newsid")})
})
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class News {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="newsid")
    private int newsid;
    @Column(name="type",table="NewsClassification")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="keywords",table="NewsClassification")
    private String keywords;
    private String url;

    @Column(name="headline",table="NewsDetail")
    private String headline;

    @Column(name="datepublished",table="NewsDetail")
    private String datePublished;

    @Column(name="datemodified",table="NewsDetail")
    private String dateModified;

    @Column(name="description",table="NewsDetail")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="articleBody",table="NewsDetail")
    private String articleBody;

    public int getNewsid() {
        return newsid;
    }

    public void setNewsid(int newsid) {
        this.newsid = newsid;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(String keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public String getDatePublished() {
        return datePublished;
    }

    public void setDatePublished(String datePublished) {
        this.datePublished = datePublished;
    }

    public String getDateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(String dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getArticleBody() {
        return articleBody;
    }

    public void setArticleBody(String articleBody) {
        this.articleBody = articleBody;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "News [newsid=" + newsid + ", type=" + type + ", keywords=" + keywords + ", url=" + url + ", headline="
                + headline + ", datePublished=" + datePublished + ", dateModified=" + dateModified + ", description="
                + description + ", articleBody=" + articleBody + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using spring and hibernate ?

Comment: @SangramBadi - No, just hibernate. I will edit the question to post hibernate config as well.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @SangramBadi - The code is similar.

Comment: can you show how `News` is defined and mapped

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran - Added in question but the mapping is deliberately wrong.

Comment: exception clearly says `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`, so try saving the object without setting `datePublished` & `dateModified` and see whether it saves properly